# how to get post data in django from iterating over different id

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a app which is quetion and 4 options.Each time it gives different 5 quetions.using a id in html page i am creating a radio button for each choice.Now how can save this value by post method in database.

**views.py**

```
def result(request,id) :
    if request.method=='POST':
        selected_choice = request.POST['choice.id']
        return redirect('list_view.html')
    else:
        return render (request,'create_view.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
path('result/<id>',views.result,name='result')
```

**html page**

```
<div>
    {% for element in q %}
     <h2>{{element.id}} .{{element.question}}</h2>
    <form  action="{% url 'app1:result' element.id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
             {% for choice in c %}
            {% if element.id == choice.id %}
            <input name="{{choice.id}}" type="radio" >{{choice.choice1}}<br>
           <input name="{{choice.id}}" type="radio" >{{choice.choice2}}<br>
           <input name="{{choice.id}}" type="radio" >{{choice.choice3}}<br>
           <input name="{{choice.id}}" type="radio" >{{choice.choice4}}<br>
        {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}<br>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question=models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice1=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    choice2=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    choice3 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    choice4 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would for sure try to go for Django forms for this. It is much easier. Check the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422465/how-to-get-radio-button-value-from-form-in-view-py-file) where it is detailed how to configure a radio button using Django forms.

Answer (score 0):

- You would like to change the input name of your choices from `{{choice.id}}` to `choiceid-{{choice-id}}`, it makes implementation easier.
- For each input radio choice field, add a value attribute, for ex:

  - `<input name="{{choice.id}}" type="radio" value="choice1">{{choice.choice1}}<br>`
- Create a `ChoiceAnswer` model with `choice` as foreign key.

```py
for key in request.POST:
    if key.startswith('choiceid-'):
        # You can access user by request.user .
        # Extract the choice here so that you can reference it in ChoiceAnswer instance.
        choice = get_object_or_404(Choice, id=key.split('-')
        if request.POST[key] == 'choice1':
        # save data in your answer model here that choice1 has been selected.
        elif request.POST[key] == 'choice2':
        # save data in your answer model here that choice2 has been selected.
```

Comment: From for loop ,should it in if request.post loop

Comment: I can't understand you. Could you please explain your comment more?